# Select least only if column exists

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query that joins 3 tables (responders, ambulances and cads*). I'm trying to display the fastest response time for each call:

*cads refer to emergency calls

```
SELECT cads.date, cads.cad_id, LEAST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cads.date, responders.arrival_time),TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cads.date,ambulances.incident_arrival_time)) AS time
FROM cads
LEFT OUTER JOIN responders ON cads.cad_id = responders.cad_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ambulances ON cads.cad_id = ambulances.cad_id
WHERE (cads.date >= '2017-08-10' AND cads.date <= '2017-08-12')
Group By cads.cad_id
```

The problem is that some calls have responders, some have ambulances and some have both. The above query only works if there is both a responder and an ambulance, and then returns null for all other times.

Check out the fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/axmTTp2BfYqTj2cNvuyDyJ/0

Comment: big thanks! you're a new member and you already created a fiddle! more new users whould do that!

Comment: @EstebanP. Glad someone appreciated that :)

Comment: Yup that's how a question should be asked

Comment: Well, the code should also be incorporated into the question - fiddles break, after all.

Comment: @Strawberry I did include the code. I didn't include the code to create all the tables because it would've made the question unnecessarily huge.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's best practice to do so.

Comment: It's also important to provide the desired result, in (an approximation of) the format in which you'd wish it to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be more than one responder or ambulance values per `cad_id`. Hence you have to first calculate the minimum responder and ambulance value per `cad_id` and then get the least between responder, ambulance:

```
SELECT cad_id,
       CASE 
          WHEN amb_min_time IS NULL THEN resp_min_time
          WHEN resp_min_time IS NULL THEN amb_min_time
          ELSE LEAST(amb_min_time, resp_min_time)
       END AS time
FROM (       
   SELECT cads.cad_id,
          MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cads.date, resp.arrival_time)) AS resp_min_time, 
          MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cads.date,amb.incident_arrival_time)) AS amb_min_time
   FROM cads
   LEFT OUTER JOIN responders AS resp ON cads.cad_id = resp.cad_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ambulances AS amb ON cads.cad_id = amb.cad_id
   WHERE (cads.date >= '2017-08-10' AND cads.date <= '2017-08-12')
   Group By cads.cad_id) AS t
```

[**Demo here**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qjjBhz3o7vgkxjnA1cm77Q/0)

Answer (score 1):

I'm expecting `min()`/`max()` because you have an aggregation query.  One method of fixing your problem is to use `COALESCE()` as in:

```
SELECT c.date, c.cad_id,
       MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, c.date,
                         GREATEST(COALESCE(r.arrival_time, a.incident_arrival_time),
                                  COALESCE(a.incident_arrival_time, r.arrival_time),
                                 )
                        ) 
          ) AS time
FROM cads c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     responders r
     ON cads.cad_id = r.cad_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     ambulances a
     ON cads.cad_id = a.cad_id
WHERE c.date >= '2017-08-10' AND c.date <= '2017-08-12'
GROUP BY c.cad_id;
```

Perhaps a simpler method is to use `union` to bring the two tables together before joining them:

```
SELECT c.date, c.cad_id,           
       MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, c.date, ra.t))  
FROM cads c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     ((SELECT r.cad_id, r.arrival_time as t
       FROM responders r
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT a.cad_id, a.incident_arrival_time
       FROM ambulances a
      )
     ) ra
     ON c.cad_id = ra.cad_id
WHERE c.date >= '2017-08-10' AND c.date <= '2017-08-12'
GROUP BY c.cad_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

`IFNULL` to the rescue!

```
SELECT cads.date, cads.cad_id, 
       LEAST(
             TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cads.date, IFNULL(responders.arrival_time, '9999-12-31 23:59:59')),
             TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cads.date, IFNULL(ambulances.incident_arrival_time, '9999-12-31 23:59:59'))
       ) AS time
FROM cads
LEFT OUTER JOIN responders ON cads.cad_id = responders.cad_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ambulances ON cads.cad_id = ambulances.cad_id
WHERE (cads.date >= '2017-08-10' AND cads.date <= '2017-08-12')
Group By cads.cad_id
```

Comment: Note that COALESCE conforms to the ANSI standard.

Comment: This seems to work! Can you clarify why you need: `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`

Comment: This is the maximum `DATETIME` value so the other value is guaranteed to be smaller (`IFNULL` or `COALESCE` returns the second value if the first one is `NULL`)

Answer (score -1):

You must change the select line:

```
SELECT cads.date, cads.cad_id, (CASE 
    WHEN responders.arrival_time is null 
        then TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cads.date,ambulances.incident_arrival_time)
    when ambulances.incident_arrival_time IS NULL
        then TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cads.date,responders.arrival_time)
    ELSE LEAST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cads.date, responders.arrival_time),TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cads.date,ambulances.incident_arrival_time))
END) AS time
FROM cads
LEFT OUTER JOIN responders ON cads.cad_id = responders.cad_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ambulances ON cads.cad_id = ambulances.cad_id
WHERE (cads.date >= '2017-08-10' AND cads.date <= '2017-08-12')
Group By cads.cad_id
```

You had a problem when the values of incident arrival time where null